# Android SipManager registration failed

Tags: android, sip, registration

I'm following Google's guidelines to create in app SIP calls as in https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html
I created a test account on sip.zadarma.com which works with a SIP client I downloaded from the Google Play however when I try to register it in my app I get:
onRegistrationFailed errorCode = -4 errorMessage: registration not running
onRegistrationFailed errorCode = -9 errorMessage: 0

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (mNumberKeyedIn == null)
        mNumberKeyedIn = "";
    if (hasSIPPermissions()) {
        initializeSIP();
    } else {
        requestSIPPermission();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    closeLocalProfile();
}

public void closeLocalProfile() {
    if (mSipManager == null) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        if (mSipProfile != null) {
            mSipManager.close(mSipProfile.getUriString());
            if (mSipManager.isRegistered(mSipProfile.getProfileName()))
                mSipManager.unregister(mSipProfile, null);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Failed to close local profile.", e);
    }
}

private void initializeSIP() {

    if (callReceiver == null) {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("com.xxxx.android.apps.xxxx.activity.INCOMING_CALL");
        callReceiver = new IncomingCallReceiver();
        this.registerReceiver(callReceiver, filter);
    }

    try {
        if (mSipManager == null) {
            mSipManager = SipManager.newInstance(this);
            if (!SipManager.isVoipSupported(this)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.sip_not_supported), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            if (SipManager.isSipWifiOnly(this)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.sip_wifi_only), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        if (mSipProfile != null) {
            closeLocalProfile();
        }

        SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder(BuildConfig.SIP_USERNAME, BuildConfig.SIP_DOMAIN);
        builder.setPassword(BuildConfig.SIP_PASSWORD);
        //builder.setProtocol("TCP");
        //builder.setAuthUserName(BuildConfig.SIP_USERNAME);
        //builder.setPort(5060);
        //builder.setOutboundProxy(BuildConfig.SIP_OUTBOUND_PROXY);
        builder.setAutoRegistration(true);
        mSipProfile = builder.build();

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("com.xxxx.android.apps.xxxx.activity.INCOMING_CALL");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
        mSipManager.open(mSipProfile, pendingIntent, null);
        mSipManager.setRegistrationListener(mSipProfile.getUriString(), new SipRegistrationListener() {

            public void onRegistering(String localProfileUri) {
                updateStatus(getString(R.string.sip_registering), R.drawable.circle_orange, false);
                Log.d(TAG, "onRegistering " + localProfileUri);
            }

            public void onRegistrationDone(String localProfileUri, long expiryTime) {
                updateStatus(getString(R.string.sip_ready), R.drawable.circle_green, true);
                Log.d(TAG, "onRegistrationDone " + localProfileUri + " expiryTime = " + expiryTime);
            }

            public void onRegistrationFailed(String localProfileUri, int errorCode,
                                             String errorMessage) {
                updateStatus(getString(R.string.sip_registration_failed), R.drawable.circle_red, false);
                Log.e(TAG, "onRegistrationFailed " + localProfileUri + " errorCode = " + errorCode + " errorMessage: " + errorMessage);
            }
        });
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.sip_not_configured), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (SipException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.oops_something_went_wrong_short), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.sip_not_supported), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Following solutions should be tried before to test your Registration server before even looking into code for SipClient.

1. Try runnig any VoIP SoftPhone client to check your server, if its not working then debug that first i.e. PortNo/IP address issue.
2. If step one is working then try running Wireshark on server to track reply from incoming REGISTRATION Request from client.

Although from "Error logs " from your text means i.e. IP address is pingable but Registration Port No is not opened.

I don't think this is code issue. It must be your setup issue for sure.